# How to make multiple Image download by single click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a requirement to allow the user to download the multiple images by checking the file and clicking the button. For now I have provided a link below every image to download.

But I need to do selecting multiple images and allow to download it by single click. For selecting multiple image, I have placed check box but don't no how to do multiple download.

Comment: when the user clicks on the button create a zip file of all the images that were checked and add the zip file to the http response so that it starts downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest compressing the files on the server side to one file and serve that.

If that is not an option you can execute a JavaScript that loops through the download links like:

Given an ordinary html with three download links.

```
<ul>
<li>
  <input name="checkbox" value="/download1.jpg">Download Image 1
</li>
<li>
  <input name="checkbox" value="/download2.jpg">Download Image 2
</li>
<li>
  <input name="checkbox" value="/download3.jpg">Download Image 3
</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" onclick="downloadSelected()">Download</a>
```

then you have following javascript. Your users will get warnings from the browser since multiple popups can be blocked.

```
  function downloadSelected() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      window.open($(this).val());
    });
    return false;
  }
```

Working example in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0ERMZ4VyXzvE0iebGMfb

Comment: need to pass img url or id?

Comment: but image is not getting download. It's opening in new window

Comment: i have tryed above method it's not getting what i am expecting is their any way to download multiple image with single click event

Comment: But it downloading in octet-stream format how to make it in image format

Comment: Content-Type is set by the server. So you probably have an issue there but it is not directly related to the problem posted here.

If the files to be downloaded are images I wonder why it responses with octet-stream.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and it's still downloading a file named 'download'. This is what my code is right now:   
 function downloadSelected() {
            $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                var img_url = $(this).val();
                var url = img_url.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
                window.open(url);
            });
            return false;
        }

Comment: Can you please attach the original html? Are the images embedded?

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    byte[] imgbyte = (byte[])dt.Rows[i]["SIte_Image"];
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgbyte, 0, imgbyte.Length);
                    img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
                    img.CssClass = "image_set";
                    img.ID = "img_" + i;
                    img.Attributes.Add("onclick", "selected_img(this.id,this.src)");
                    createsubDiv.Controls.Add(img);

Comment: img_url.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream'); 

to

    img_url.replace(/^data:image\/jpg\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');

Comment: Thanks for response but it opening in new window not downloading the image :(